# kubernetes command: wget - http:myfilelocation.co.za doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift

i want to use command: - wget to download a file and put in a volume gunzip since it is a gz format. but somehow the container fails as soon as i hit the kubectl apply -f command. the Pod status displays Error. what could i be doing wrong?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    app: example-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-app
        image: docker.source.co.za/azp/example-app:1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - wget
        - "-O"
        - http://confluence.source.co.za/download/attachments/627674073/refpolicies.tar.gz
        volumeMounts:
        - name: example-app
          mountPath: /config/
          readOnly: true

      volumes:
      - name: example-app
        emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: What does a `kubectl  describe` and `kubectl  logs` say?

Comment: ok i ran that command. im getting Reason: CrashLoopBackOff, state:waiting

Comment: logs returns: wget: missing URL

Comment: i have provided the url or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you read [wget manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)? Logs are saying wget is missing url because wget thinks the url you provided is a file name as its preceded by `-O`.

Comment: so ive removed the -O and logged the container, im getting a refpolicies.tar.gz: Permission denied and annot write to 'refpolicies.tar.gz' (No such file or directory).

Comment: this is actually permissions issue, how do i solve this ?

Comment: Is it possible that by any chance your container's WORKDIR is set to `/config`? or maybe your container is running as nonroot user which doesn't have permissions to write to directory.

Comment: i just ran whoami and it seems like im a "default" user not root

Comment: how can i add these permission to a dockerfile so i am root user?

Comment: You could use `runAsUser: 0` in pod spec to run container as root user. Here is [an example in k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod).

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Sorry for not replying back man. yes it did work out.